# Automatically update number data from one book to another by matching text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So in other words. I have say two columns. First column all rows are numbers and the second column all rows are corresponding text fields. I have two books both books have say 95% the same text fields and mostly identical with the exception of the 5%. Wanting to know if there is a way that I can have the number fields of the first book overwrite the numbers of the second book by matching the number of the first book to the same text field of the second book?

Answer (score 0):

Sample data and desired output is always helpful to avoid invalid answers. If I correctly understand your question, then a vlookup will work. First you need to rearrange your columns in Book 1 by having the text column first.

Here's the formula for cell C2 in Book 2:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,[test_Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

We're not overwriting, but rather, just adding another column in Book 2 with the number you want to use. You can wrap an error formula around the formula if some of the text values in book 2 are not found in book 1, like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,[test_Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE),A2)
```

Copy it down, and you're done. Clean up as needed.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. I will test it out.